# How to conditionally navigate to a page developed by page layout and the aura wrapper component on page load for creating opportunities?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to Salesforce and am working on something already developed. Currently, I have a requirement to navigate a user with a specific profile to the page created using the page layout option (say, OpportuntyForAdminByLayout) if it meets a condition. There is a lightning override configured (using AuraWrapper) as well. I need to have both. If the condition is met, then it must go to the page OpportuntyForAdminByLayout; otherwise, it should work with the Aura Wrapper.

Have tries like this but not worked.

```
 doInit: function(cmp) {
    console.log("Inside init function!!");
    var action = cmp.get("c.fetchUser");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      console.log('state is '+state);
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
          var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
          cmp.set("v.profileName", storeResponse);
         var a = cmp.get('c.redirectToNewPage');
         $A.enqueueAction(a);
       
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
redirectToNewPage:function(cmp)
{
  var navService = cmp.find("navService");
    if('System Administrator'== cmp.get("v.profileName"))
    {
    var pageReference = new PageReference('/apex/3H000000Xfc3QAC');
    
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did i solved it is by calling Record Type for navigating .(Before I was trying to use Page Layout).

```
      var recordTypeId = '<record_id>'; 
      var url = '/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?recordTypeId=' + recordTypeId + '&nooverride=1';
      var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
      navEvt.setParams({
          "url": url
      });
      navEvt.fire()
```